# couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access application bundle in ios

Tags: ios, swift3

When i am copy files from document directory to application bundle directory it gives error like this :

**“Images” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “Resources”.**

My code

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentDirectoryPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("Images")
let bundleDirectoryPath = (Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("GCDWebUploader.bundle").appendingPathComponent("Contents").appendingPathComponent("Resources").appendingPathComponent("Images"))

do {
        try fileManager.copyItem(at: documentDirectoryPath!, to: bundleDirectoryPath!)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Couldn't copy file to final location! Error:\(error.description)")
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to move images to your bundle directory?

Comment: I have implemented simple webserver  with the use of GCDWebUploader.And Its done successfully.but now i want to display uploaded image from iphone to web.At that time i got issue of resource not found.So for that i got solution of copy resource.but doing that i am getting issue of permission.

Comment: Does this mean you have an image in your documents directory which you want to upload to external server(using GCDWebUploader)? If that is the case, why don't you show your upload code, how you are accessing image from sandbox?

Comment: Are you know about GCDWebServer?see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345909/what-is-gcdwebserver-for

Comment: I read about GCDWebserver on github. It is a neat library. Now I understand, you want to fetch image from your iOS app, acting as a web server. I have still not understood, why you want to copy the image file from documents directory to bundle directory.

Comment: I don't want to copy file from document directory to application resource folder but while i am display image in web at that time i getting error in console like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404".so i am trying to copy document directory to resource folder. but it is not possible.

Comment: So the problem is in implementation of GCDWebUploadServer. You must debug that or ask a separate question posting and explaining a bit of your code and I am sure someone who has worked on that framework will help you out.

Comment: Yes, I have already asked question in GCDWebUploader Github issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why copying to Bundle Dirctory.. There is no way to write in the bundle directory because the bundle dir is code signed with `SSL certificate` and you can't break it. You can use the documents directory itself for storing files.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle directory(Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle)) on disk is immutable by code, i.e a developer cannot change its contents. The documents directory(sandbox) of your application is where you want to keep things.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add any files to the bundle directory, it must be done at build time using copy resources in the build phases tab. These are usually files that should not be changed for every execution.

If the images you are trying to add to the bundle are for UI. use an asset catalog

For any other type of file (reading or writing) use the documents directory